# Why do I have a large PVC pipe venting warm air outside intermittently?

Tags: hvac, vent, pvc

There is a large PVC pipe (3 actually) which vent air intermittently.  I started noticing I could see steam rising over my deck in the morning and then I found that these pipes vent air at least a couple times per hour.

What is the purpose of this venting?  I'm concerned about efficiency.

Bonus: When the pipes are venting it is fairly noisy.  When we're on our deck we can hear it and it's annoying.  Any way to muffle this noise without impacting the operation?

Comment: If I was to justify a downvote for this question it would be because the question doesn't say where the pipe is, what sort of equipment is in the home, etc. It's rather vague.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a high efficiency furnace? If so this is the exhaust and air intake for your furnace.  Unlike older furnaces, HE furnaces do not necessarily exhaust up through your chimney and instead often use PVC or ABS pipes.

I'm not sure about the third pipe though. Do you have a heat exchanger?

The best way to know for sure what they are is to try and trace them back to the source.

Comment: Well, HE furnaces _can_ exhaust up the chimney... But because their exhaust tends to be more acidic that can require lining the chimney, and because it's lower temperature they don't have to do so. A PVC exhaust pipe is a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said this sounds like furnace exhaust, though there are other possibilities like dryer vent.

Neither should be very noisy, though. If it's a high frequency noise, check for partial blockage like bird's nest (though there should be a screen preventing that). If it's a low frequency noise there may be resonances in how it was mounted; you'd have to find it inside and figure out where it's vibrating and how to modify the mounting to reduce that.

If it isn't one of those, you still need to find it and figure out where the noise is actually occurring.